# How to decode html code in textareafor?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have written following code to accept html tag as data in my model

```
 [AllowHtml]
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Post Content Required")]
 public string PostContent { get; set; }
```

It accepts it but when I call data back it displays the data with html tag like:

```
<h2><strong>&lt;p&gt;&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;[...] store and many other 
&amp;amp;hellip;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;&lt;/p&gt;</strong></h2>
```

I have tried to write `@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.PageContent)` but it doesn't remove tags..

Comment: Are you trying to strip HTML tags or are you trying to show the raw text including tags? What source are you trying to generate?

Comment: Ehm, the fact that this text starts with `<p>` and ends with `</p>`, and the decoded text also starts with `<p>` and ends with `</p>` doesn't mean that HtmlDecode hasn't done anything!

Comment: But i want just simple text without <p> .... </p> so what should i do???

Answer (score 0):

Use @Html.Raw to output raw HTML code. However this can expose your site to script attacks so use carefully.

Comment: I have tried @Html.Raw but it displays the text with formatting as i have formatted it in Editor but still displays the tags as well..

Answer (score 0):

Since you have allow html already on the field I would just convert the ascii over to html before you send it to the view.  something like

```
public string Decode(string value)
    {
        return (value)
            .Replace("&quot;", "\"")
            .Replace("&lt;", "<")
            .Replace("&gt;", ">");
    }

    public string Encode(string value)
    {
        return (value)
          .Replace("\"", "&quot;")
          .Replace("'", "''")
          .Replace("<", "&lt;")
          .Replace(">", "&gt;");
    }
```

then you can encode it again before saving to the database.  Hopefully this helps